# Generalization of fully faithful functors between $sSet-$enriched categories

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

If we have two $sSet$ enriched categories $C$ and $D$ is there a name for a $sSet-$enriched functor $G:C \rightarrow D$ such that the map $C(x,y) \rightarrow D(Gx,Gy)$ is a weak equivalence of simplicial sets? This could be a simplicial generalization of the concept of a fully faithful functor between $sSet-$enriched categories.

Comment: If you add the request that $G$ be essentially surjective, this is the definition of a Dwyer-Kan equivalence. Then, if you're using $sSet$-enriched categories as models for $\infty$-categories, this is simply a "fully-faithful functor of $\infty$-categories"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many references write “homotopically fully faithful” for such an enriched functor.